# AVD doesn't load correctly. Looks nothing like the tutorials I've tried

Tags: android

When i select my virtual device in eclipse and click start this is all I get.

[image]

Yet in all the tutorials I've tried that have screen shots to help aid the reader, their AVD looks like this

[image]

There are also some other inconsistencies with how in these tutorials (vogella and android developers) the screen shots have options and sections that I don't have even when I follow the directions to a T. AND OF COURSE THE SIMPLE HELLO WORLD PROGRAM IS NOT RUNNING WHEN I TRY IT IN THE AVD

Can't understand why it's different for me and not working.
I'm using windows xp home sp3 32 bit with 1.5 gigs of ram

Comment: Your AVD is still loading... it takes time to start up.

Answer (score 3):

wait for the first time,open console and see what it logs, if red error appears "failed to launch, timeout or other ... (it's in the worst scenario, it's here time to panic), or simply when You'll see your second(good) screenshot - loaded device - just run once again.

first booting could be up to 5 min (2gb ram),

when it finally appears, I hope, (loaded desktop with icons) dont close it, until you're really need RAM for other PC tasks.

btw there are some common advices how to speed up booting:

• snapshot

• custom ini file

• disable booting animation

• use real device

• use host GPU , in virtual device settings (for faster response, when avd is already loaded)

• smaller screen size ( for typical hello worlds 320x480 would be ok)

Answer (score 0):

i takes time to load. Like booting up your phone. Once it's open don't close it. you can run and test your app on the same emulator. Remember, once you close, it takes time to load again. Upgrading your ram might help boost up the speed